# О постановке независимой запятой перед тире

Tags: пунктуация

Если между частями предложения, разделенного союзом **но** или составным союзом **если... то** стоит тире, сохраняется ли там еще и запятая? Если тире (без запятой) перед **то** еще может ставится как интонационное, то информации о тире и запятой перед **но** не нашла ни в одном справочнике. Правда, встретила парную постановку этих знаков в одной книге, из чего делаю вывод, что это все-таки возможно.

Делегируйте задачи — но всегда контролируйте и подсказывайте!

Приятно слышать такую высокую оценку работы предприятия — но это только внешне все так.

Что касается производственного процесса и ведения продаж — то ее модель я закладывал изначально.

Нет никакого секрета, а если бы был — то я б его не стал раскрывать.

Answer (score 2):

**А в правилах Лопатина разве информация не на эту тему?**

§ 114. Между частями сложносочиненного предложения ставится тире, если вторая часть предложения заключает в себе значение результата, следствия, резкого противопоставления (чаще перед союзом и, реже перед союзами но, а):

Надо успеть записать. Малейшая задержка — и мысль, блеснув, исчезнет (Пауст.); По дубу перейдем ручей — и на болото (Пришв.); Положишь палочку на воду — и она поплывет по течению (Пришв.);

**Примечание.** Между частями сложносочиненного предложения может стоять запятая и тире **как единый знак препинания**: Оскалив зубы, староста стал драть его кнутом по чем попало, — и от боли и от ужаса Аверкий проснулся весь в слезах (Бун.). Такое разделение частей сложносочиненного предложения **несколько устарело.**

Употребление запятой и тире как единого знака препинания **следует отличать от сочетания запятой и тире, когда каждый знак стоит на собственном основании**: Кто знает, сколько придется пробыть в тайге, — и все время будет за спиной Гринька и его товарищи (Шукш.) — запятая закрывает придаточную часть предложения, а тире разделяет части сложносочиненного предложения.

Comment: Да, спасибо Вам большое. Я помню, что просматривала этот материал, но на скобки не обратила внимания. Увидела, что везде "и", а примеров с этими союзами нету.

Answer (score 0):

1. В предложении **"Нет никакого секрета, а если бы был — то я б его не стал раскрывать"** постановка тире допустима на двух основания: 1) придаточное условное предшествует главной части; 2) придаточная часть имеет неполный состав. ***См.: Розенталь Д.Э. Мправочник по пунктуации. М., 1984. С. 163.***
2. Предложения типа ***"Что касается производственного процесса и ведения продаж — то ее модель я закладывал изначально" обычно рассматриваются как квазисложные (см. работы В.А. Белошапковой и др.).*** Сочетание "что касается" оценивается как устойчивый оборот, используемый для выделения темы высказывания. Чаще всего такой оборот выделяется запятыми, но при неполноте основной части возможно и тире. В Вашем примере достаточно будет поставить просто запятую.

   3.***В предложениях "Делегируйте задачи — но всегда контролируйте и подсказывайте!" и "Приятно слышать такую высокую оценку работы предприятия — но это только внешне все так"*** постановка тире (без запятой) возможна: тире подчеркивает в этом случае резкость противопоставления и присоединительный характер второй части. Постановка тире с запятой между частями сложносочиненного предложения "несколько устарело" (Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник. М., 2009. С. 250).