Запятая перед тире нужна ли в данном случае
Нужна ли запятая перед тире в таком предложении:

Я была уверена, что извиняться передо мной никто не собирается, — зубы
заговаривают.


Нужно ли тире после запятой..

Правильно:
Я была уверена, что извиняться передо мной никто не собирается, — зубы заговаривают.
Пояснение

Тему можно посмотреть у Розенталя § 64. Запятая и тире

В большинстве случаев каждый из этих знаков препинания ставится на собственном основании:
Его походка была небрежна и ленива, но я заметил, что он не 
размахивал руками, — первый признак некоторой скрытности 
характера (Л.) — запятая закрывает придаточную часть 
сложноподчиненного предложения, тире поставлено перед 
своеобразным приложением к предшествующим словам, имеет 
присоединительный оттенок;
Я отвечал, что меня беспокоят мухи, — и мы оба замолчали 
(Л.) — запятая закрывает придаточную часть, тире поставлено 
 перед частью предложения, выражающей следствие.

Необходимость постановки тире в качестве дополнительного знака препинания определяется контекстом.

Таким образом, решение должно быть конкретным для каждого случая.  В заданном предложении второе сообщение имеет присоединительный характер, причем относится ко всей первой части. Пауза увеличенная, запятая закрывает придаточное.

Для сравнения


Я была уверена, что извиняться передо мной они не собираются — зубы заговаривают.
Здесь я бы поставила только тире, так как последнее сообщение относится к придаточному. Это видно из аналога этого предложения:
Я была уверена, что извиняться передо мной никто не собирается, а просто зубы заговаривают.

Задачу можно решить методом блоков по Лопатину. Здесь три предикативные основы и два блока. Отношения между блоками присоединительные, но в первом случае требуется более сильный знак (запятая и тире).

ПРИЛОЖЕНИЕ
Примеры обсуждения темы на форуме
https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474472/Нужна-ли-запятая-перед-тире-в-следующих-предложениях
https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/474885/Нужно-ли-закрывать-запятой-придаточное-в-заданном-предложении/474894#474894
https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/418722/О-постановке-независимой-запятой-перед-тире/418731#418731

Шарон, в обоих случаях присоединительная часть относится к придаточному, наличие запятой от изменения одного слова в придаточном не зависит.

Серж, откуда у вас это правило?  Тогда я вам скажу, что в моем примере  отношения не присоединительные, а другие. Скажу, что последнее сообщение входит в придаточное, и тире обозначает пропуск. Не важно, как назвать, но важно, как слышать(там пауза короче). Вот это предложение  с однородными сказуемыми: Извиняться передо мной они не собираются — зубы заговаривают.

Но два предложения одинаковые. Только в втором изменилось одно слово.

Это я его изменила, чтобы отношения между сказуемыми были однородными. Получилась присоед. конструкция в составе придаточного, а это важно. // У Розенталя:  Пишут, чтобы мы обязательно приезжали — будут встречать.  Почему здесь нет запятой, объясните  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=151  пункт 7.

Я понимаю, постановка знаков препинания зависит от структуры предложения, а не от одного слова в предложении.

Я об этом же хотела вам напомнить, но вот вы сами отвечаете. Вам кажется, что я меняю слова, а я меняю грамматическую форму. В исходном варианте безличное предложение и неопределенно-личное предложение, а в измененном - два неопределенно-личных предложения, которые близки по значению к однородным сказуемым. Нюансы?  Их надо видеть и слышать, в этом мастерство Розенталя, в отличие от современных специалистов,  // Вспомню и метод блоков Лопатина, который никто не хочет применять для анализа. Это такое правило над правилами, когда требуется обращать внимание на нюансы.

Но разве можно поменять структуру предложения, изменив одно слово? Никто не собирается извиняться и Они не собираются извиняться - какие это предложения? Безличное предложение и  неопределенно-личное предложение? Но ведь в обоих указан субъект.

Серж, но для безличных предложений при отсутствии грамматического подлежащего все же существует семантический субъект действия. И вот в этой они разные: никто и неопределенное кто-то.

И все же: никто - здесь подлежащее, которое стоит в им.пад.

Ну да, вы правы, здесь двусоставное и неопр.-личное предложение (безличного нет), но все равно это разные структуры.  А я как раз в своем примере делаю их одинаковыми.

Шарон, можно вам на почту отправить кое-какой материал по русскому? Вернее аттестационные тесты.

А что это за тесты? Чем они интересны?

Согласен с Шарон, что разные структуры: никто не собирается извиняться - они зубы заговаривают // две разных основы. Они не собираются извиняться - зубы заговаривают // Тут близко к однородным

Интересны тем, что многие учителя возмущаются, говорят, что трудные, многие не могут набрать нужный балл. Хотя, должен признать,  что особой сложности нет, но есть спорные вопросы.

@Серж, А вы укажите мне тогда на спорные вопросы и пришлите материалы, а я их посмотрю.  Может на форуме кое-что обсудим. Так будет интереснее, и пользы больше

Хорошо, вышлю на почту.

Вот что ответили лингвисты сайта Современный русский.
В данной позиции логично поставить только тире без запятой, поскольку "что извиняться передо мной никто не собирается" и "зубы заговаривают" по смыслу максимально приближены к однородным придаточным, а знак тире указывает на их смысловое противопоставление.
В этом предложении ( Лермонтов, прим. - мое.) текст, выделенный жирным шрифтом ситуация иная: здесь "первый признак некоторой скрытности характера" вряд ли можно расценивать как вариант однородного придаточного к "что он не размахивал руками", скорее эта часть относится по смыслу к "я заметил...". И еще один нюанс: дело в том, что у Д.Э. Розенталя не так уж редки случаи, когда он берет какой-то случай сугубо авторской пунктуации (а в случае с Лермонтовым это вполне очевидно так) и им иллюстрирует то или иное общее правило, иначе говоря, использует единичные и далеко не всегда соответствующие норме примеры как доказательство некоей широкой тенденции в синтаксисе или - реже - орфографии. Не пытаемся пошатнуть авторитет большого ученого, но это действительно так :)
